# Programmatically UIPanGestureRecognizer not doing anything

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have the folling UIView with a gesture recognizer that calls a function like so:

```
let cardView: UIView = {
    let cv = UIView()

    cv.backgroundColor = .red
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.layer.cornerRadius = 5     
    cv.layer.masksToBounds = true     
    cv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cv.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan)))

    return cv
}()
```

and the implementation of the gesture recognizer like this:

```
// pan functionality
func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)

    if let card = gesture.view {
        card.center = CGPoint(x: card.center.x + translation.x, y: card.center.y + translation.y)

    }

}
```

However, when I try to move the card in the view controller nothing happens.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: add breakpoint in handlePan function and check if it call or not, then I think you have to self the delegate of the gesture.

Comment: @Mina the function appears to not ever be called. I tried `cv.delegate = self` but got an error

Comment: what is the error?
you probably should implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate (inheritance

Comment: the error is `value of type 'UIView' has no member 'delegate`

Comment: check your view frame

Comment: declare your cardView  as class variable not inside any method and then in your handle pan as func handlePan(_ gesture:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: self.view)
    cardView  .center = CGPoint(x: cardView.center.x + translation.x, y: cardView .center.y + translation.y)
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
}

Comment: @luckyShubhra cardView is a class variable, the issue is that the handlePan function isn't being called at all

Comment: Remove this line  `cv.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan)))` from your view declarartion. Below that add ` var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.handlePan(_:)))`  `panGesture.delegate = self` 'cv.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)'

Comment: have your checked your view hierarchy. There might be some view on top of your cardview which may hinder the interaction.

Comment: I fixed the function call issue by changing `cardView` from a `let` statement to a `lazy var`. The problem is now solved.